# How to handle independently with errors of multiple uniques in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, error-handling, unique

I have a Schema with multiple uniques like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  }
});
```

During a save trying I know that I can access the property `err.code` **(11000)** to handle unique errors, like this:

```
user.save((err, doc) => {
    if(!err) {
      res.send(doc);
    } else {
      if (err.code == 11000)
        res.status(422).send(['Message here!']);
    }
  });
```

So, in this case I'd like to set custom messages for both fields: **user** and **email**.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do that by sending the **`object error`** and checking its propreties, and noticed that there is a property called **keyPattern**.

So, the code is working fine:

```
user.save((err, doc) => {
    if(!err) {
      res.send(doc);
    } else {
      if (err.code == 11000)
        if(Object.keys(err.keyPattern)[0] === "user")
          res.status(422).send(['Duplicate user!']);
        else if(Object.keys(err.keyPattern)[0] === "email")
          res.status(422).send(['Duplicate email!']);
    }
  });
```